# Initialize int[][,] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

How I do Initialize this:

```
public const int[][,] Map = ...
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
public const int[][,] Map = {
    { // Map 1
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
    },
    { // Map 2
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
    },
    // etc.
};
```

I don't want to create an `int[,,] Map`, because somewhere else I want to do:

```
loader.Load(Map[map_numer]); // Load method recieve an int[,]
```

Comment: FYI: "const" means "is a compile-time-determined number or string". "readonly" means "this field is initialized once and then never changes".  Note that a readonly field containing an array, the FIELD cannot be changed to refer to a different array, but the array elements can be changed; if you intend the array elements to be unchanging then consider using another data structure, like ReadOnlyCollection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int[][,] a = new int[][,]
{
    new int[,]
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},

    },
    new int[,]
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks!. It works, but `Map` can't be a `const` (The compiler throw me an error if `Map` is `const`

Comment: `readonly`. Ok! I'm new to C# and I've never seen the `readonly` keyword, I have to remeber this next time.